# NodeJs and Socket IO how to connect two users

Tags: android, ios, node.js, socket.io

I am new to NodeJs & socketIO. I am a backend developer, I am developing android chat app backend code, I am using NodeJs and SocketIO as backend server.

My application is like dating app. User will search for gender and need to pick the gender user which are online and connect both the users.

Can any one give me better way to develop this logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can write both Apis and chat server code in the same codebase, so nodejs would be an ideal option for your purpose.

From the given information, I hope you've a user table.
So whenever one user interacts with another user , consider it as conversation. So you can use either rooms/chatid for a conversation. It will be unique b/w 2 people.
Even you can create chat groups using socketio rooms concept. So save the conversation ids/roomids in a separate table.

So table structure should be like this:

- User table (info about all users)
- Conversation table (info about conversation/room ids)
- Chat table (all chats)

*SocketIO Implementation*

Each client(android/ios app) will establish a connection with server, so there will be a unique socketid b/w a client and socket server
 - Save all socketids to db.
 - So whenever a user wants to connect with another user, the server can easily find out that user's socketid and you can send chats across these connections.

All the very best !!!

**References**

1. https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/
2. https://socket.io/demos/chat/
3. https://michaelheap.com/sending-messages-to-certain-clients-with-socket-io/